# Incrementing and decrementing the date from where it stopped

Tags: javascript, html, angular, date, typescript

This is my controller:

```
private day: any = '';
private add: number = 0;
private remove: number = 0;
private days: any = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

dayBefore() {
    let now = new Date();
    this.remove += 1;
    let newDate = this.decrementDays(now, this.remove);
    this.day = this.days[newDate.getDay()];
}

dayAfter() {
    let now = new Date();
    this.add += 1;
    let newDate = this.incrementDays(now, this.add);
    this.day = this.days[newDate.getDay()];
}

dayToday() {
    let now = new Date();
    this.day = this.days[now.getDay()];
    this.add = 0;
    this.remove = 0;
}

decrementDays: any = function removeDay(date: any, days: any) {
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - days, date.getHours(), date.getSeconds(), date.getMilliseconds());
};

incrementDays: any = function addDay(date: any, days: any) {
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + days, date.getHours(), date.getSeconds(), date.getMilliseconds());
};
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li (click)="dayBefore()"></li>
    <li (click)="dayToday()"></li>
    <li (click)="dayAfter()"></li>
</ul>

<span>{{day}}</span>
```

The problem with this is, though incrementation and decrementation works, when I want to go to `dayBefore()` after the `dayAfter()` I do not go to the date immediately that is on the day before.

If I click on `dayAfter()` it will take me to `Tuesday` (if today is `Monday`) `and` when I click on `dayBefore()` it will take me on `Sunday`, instead to Monday. How exactly can I fix this? I know why is this happening. It is because it is starting to count from today's date (`Monday`), not from where I stopped it.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Just a remark, please do not write `days: any = ["Sunday", ...` you are throwing away valuable information and writing more code than you need to. Write `days = ["Sunday", ...` instead.

Comment: Use only one variable to keep track of how many days were added/removed. So, instead of two variables `add` and `remove` use just one and change it by one inside the `dayBefore` and `dayAfter` functions.

Comment: Give me a minute guys :)

Comment: Still, it didn't solve the issue I have presented..

Comment: You have too many functions and variables. It is basically like @Titus said. Having increment and decrement is also unnecessary.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, please post your answer . Thhanks.

Comment: @eric.dummy answered

Comment: @AluanHaddad, thanks, give me a min.

Comment: Works like a charm.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Component({
  // boilerplate and ceremony
})
export class DayOfWeekComponent {
  days = [
    "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
  ];

  dayOfWeek = new Date().getDay();

  resetDayOfWeek() {
    this.dayOfWeek = new Date().getDay();
  }

  offsetDayOfWeek(offset: number) {
    let dayOfWeek = (this.dayOfWeek + offset) % 7;
    if (dayOfWeek < 0) {
      dayOfWeek += 7;
    }
    this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<ul>
    <li (click)="offsetDayOfWeek(-1)">Previous</li>
    <li (click)="resetDayOfWeek()">Today</li>
    <li (click)="offsetDayOfWeek(1)">Next</li>
</ul>

<span>{{days[dayOfWeek]}}</span>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/7is6uMGtkvcQ5V4VzqYp?p=preview

Comment: I had a bug, factor is 7 not 6 :o

Comment: I noticed, fixed it. :) 

What is the logic behind 8 days?

Comment: good point, I fixed that as well. Need to take modulus first.

Comment: You don't need to, it still worked, but now is probably cleaner. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private day: any = '';
private add: number = 0;
private remove: number = 0;
private days: any = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
private today = new Date();

dayBefore() {
    let newDate = this.decrementDays(1);
    this.day = this.days[newDate.getDay()];
}

dayAfter() {
    let newDate = this.incrementDays(1);
    this.day = this.days[newDate.getDay()];
}

dayToday() {
    this.today = new Date();
    this.day = this.days[this.today.getDay()];
}

decrementDays: any = function removeDay(days: any) {
let date = this.today;
this.today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - days, date.getHours(), date.getSeconds(), date.getMilliseconds());
return this.today;
};

incrementDays: any = function addDay(days: any) {
let date = this.today;
this.today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + days, date.getHours(), date.getSeconds(), date.getMilliseconds());
return this.today;
};
```

This can be further refactored and can be made simpler. I just made a quick fix.

Comment: @eric.dummy what issue are you facing now?

Comment: @eric.dummy It was passing a variable. I changed it to a constant. Did it work?

Comment: dayToday() isn't working, everything else seems to be working just fine :)

Comment: @eric.dummy did you want it to be the current day always?

Comment: It is already current day, but I want it to revert to current day once I click on it as well..

Comment: @eric.dummy Updated. Should work as your expectation :)

Comment: Thanks mate, but sorry, Im going to to with Aluan's solution. Hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: @eric.dummy No problem :)